# I have the materials but I can't craft a White Phasesaber

Tags: terraria

I've gotten my White Phaseblade. I've collected my 50 Crystal Shards. Standing in front of my Lead Anvil. No White Phasesaber in the crafting menu.

I played Terraria a whole bunch about a year before v1.3 released, and I made several Phasesabers.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You mention having a lead anvil but you must have a mythril/orichalcum anvil to craft the [Phasesaber](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Phasesaber). This was changed with the [release of 1.3.0.1](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Phasesaber#History).